# Trying to understand .strip

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, strip

I have a file, called `input.py`, which contains the following:

```
#This is a file of categories
Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger
Items:      desk, chair, bus, cups, pencil

Technology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router
    #That's the end of the file
```

and I want to filter out all blank lines and lines starting with `#` to produce `output.py`:

```
Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger
Items:      desk, chair, bus, cups, pencil
Technology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router
```

My code is

```
with open('input.py', 'r') as infile, open('output.py', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line[0].strip('') == '#' or line == '\n':
            pass
        else:
            outfile.write(line)
```

but it doesn't strip off the line starting with a tab. I've tried replacing `.strip('')` with `.strip('\t')` but I get the same output:

```
Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger
Items:      desk, chair, bus, cups, pencil
Technology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router
    #That's the end of the file
```

Why is `.strip('')` or `.strip('\t')` not stripping off the tab?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `if line[0].strip() == '#'` as well, same output.

Comment: Why are you calling a non-python file `.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to actually apply `strip` for applicable lines in your `else` condition. In addition, use `str.startswith` to test for whether your line begins with a specific string.

Here's a complete example:

```
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger
Items:      desk, chair, bus, cups, pencil

Technology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router
    #That's the end of the file""")

with mystr as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip().startswith('#') or line == '\n':
            pass
        else:
            print(line.strip())
```

Result:

```
Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger
Items:      desk, chair, bus, cups, pencil
Technology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router
```

Comment: Your code just produces onw long string:
`Animals: cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tigerItems:  desk, chair, bus, cups, pencilTechnology: cellphone, TV, laptop, wifi-router`

Comment: @Jim421616, Did you copy-paste my code correctly? My answer is designed to help. To adapt it to your code, you may have to add `outfile.write('\n')` to your code at the appropriate place....

Comment: Ah, ok. I've un-downvoted your answer, thanks. I still can't see why my code doesn't strip the `\t` in the first place.

Comment: @Jim421616, Well, basically `outfile.write(line)` does not `strip` for you.. At this stage you haven't told Python to use `line.strip()`. You only use it in your `if` condition earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Strip method can only remove characters from beginning or end of the string. Try using replace instead.

```
>>> line = "Animals:    cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger"
>>> line.replace('\t', ' ')
'Animals: cat, dog, frog, cheetah, tiger'
```